# Arduino int to String conversion

Tags: c++, string, arduino, int

I have this code:

```
String c = String(BTLEserial.read());
char relevant = c.charAt(0);
Serial.println(relevant);
```

where `BTLEserial.read()` returns type `Int`.  I'm converting that to a `String`, in the first line so that I can use the `charAt` function on it in the next.

When I send my Bluetooth "0000", my `println(relevant)` prints `4`.

I made a test println() statement to print the value of c, and found that its value when BTLEserial.read() is `0000` turns out to be `48`.  This tells me that I have a conversion problem, when I change the `Int` value `BTLEserial.read()` to a string, `c`.

What's happening here, and what's the right way to convert `BTLEserial.read()` to type `String`?

Comment: Why are you convinced that the "crazy integer values" you are seeing are not the first character read from the bluetooth?   Please provide more details and an example output...

Comment: The first character in the string sent to my Bluetooth is 0, and the character the Serial.println() line prints is 8.

Comment: _Constructing a String from a number results in a string that contains the ASCII representation of that number._ as the docs say, so your construction is correct.

Comment: It's very confusing that you changed (edit 3) the `charAt(1)` to `charAt(0)` and still see the same output.  Is the question about how the `String.charAt` function works now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I made a test println() statement to print the value of c, and found that its value when BTLEserial.read() is `0000` turns out to be `48`.

Hardly surprising. The ASCII value of "0" is 48.

The "int" that `Adafruit_BLE_UART::read()` returns is the most recent byte received; if you want to receive multiple bytes, e.g. the string "0000", then you will need to call it multiple times, adding the character to a buffer each time.

Comment: This was it!  Great insight into the read() function, as well as the implicit ASCII conversion that was happening in my string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the first character of your `String` object is at index 0?  So actually, you're reading one character *behind* your string (It doesn't contain a null character as for [the docs](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringLength)).

A convenient String implementation should throw an exception or at least warn you that you're reading out of bounds.  But on Arduino you need to verify your bounds-check yourself (hey, it's embedded).

Comment: Good catch, but either way it should not have returned 8, since 8 is not present anywhere in the string.

Comment: Responding to your edit, correct me if I'm wrong, but charAt(1) is not out of bounds, since an index of 1 would just be the 2nd character.  Not the first, as I intended, but also not out of bounds.